# Makefile - .o: file not recognized: File truncated?

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, dependencies, gnu-make

I'm just learning GNU make, but I'm having trouble linking when using .d (dependency) files. Can anyone point me in the right direction with this **error**:

`...../part1.o: file not recognized: File truncated 
recipe for target 'bin/target/prog' failed`

It's a simple program containing: *main.cpp, part1.cpp, part1.h, part2.cpp, part2.h*

Where part1 and part2 have a method to print something.

**This is from terminal when running make:**

I don't get why I'm getting a warning for using *#pragma once*?

```
stud@GoldenImageASE:~/Desktop/ISU/L1/2$ make ARCH=target -f Makefile.th
Compiling...part2.cpp
arm-devkit-g++ -MTbuild/target/part2.o -MM -I. part2.cpp > build/target/part2.d
Compiling...part1.cpp
arm-devkit-g++ -MTbuild/target/part1.o -MM -I. part1.cpp > build/target/part1.d
Compiling...main.cpp
arm-devkit-g++ -MTbuild/target/main.o -MM -I. main.cpp > build/target/main.d
object file....main.o
arm-devkit-g++ -I. -c main.cpp part1.h part2.h > build/target/main.o
part1.h:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file
 #pragma once
         ^
part2.h:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file
 #pragma once
         ^
object file....part1.o
arm-devkit-g++ -I. -c part1.cpp > build/target/part1.o
object file....part2.o
arm-devkit-g++ -I. -c part2.cpp > build/target/part2.o
arm-devkit-g++ -I. -o build/target/main.o build/target/part1.o build/target/part2.o -o prog
build/target/part1.o: file not recognized: File truncated
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.th:27: recipe for target 'bin/target/prog' failed
make: *** [bin/target/prog] Error 1
```

**My Makefile is found below:**

```
# Variables
SOURCES=main.cpp part1.cpp part2.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
DEPS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.d)
EXE=prog
CXXFLAGS =-I.


# Making for host
# > make ARCH=host
ifeq (${ARCH},host)
CXX=g++
BUILD_DIR=build/host
EXE_DIR=bin/host
endif

# Making for target
# > make ARCH= target
ifeq (${ARCH},target)
CXX=arm-devkit-g++
BUILD_DIR=build/target
EXE_DIR=bin/target
endif

$(addprefix ${EXE_DIR}/,$(EXE)): $(addprefix ${BUILD_DIR}/,$(DEPS)) $(addprefix ${BUILD_DIR}/,$(OBJECTS))
# << Check the $(DEPS) new dependency
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(addprefix ${BUILD_DIR}/,$(OBJECTS))

$(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, %.o): %.cpp
    @echo "object file...."$*.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^ > $@


# Rule that describes how a .d ( dependency ) file is created from a .cpp
# Similar to the assigment %. cpp -> %.o
${BUILD_DIR}/%.d: %.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @echo "Compiling..."$<
    $(CXX) -MT$(@:.d=.o) -MM $(CXXFLAGS) $^ > $@

debug:
    @echo "DEPS: "$(DEPS)"\n"
    @echo "OBJ: " $(addprefix ${BUILD_DIR}/,$(OBJECTS))"\n"
    @echo "EXE: " $(addprefix ${EXE_DIR}/,$(EXE))"\n"


.PHONY:clean
clean: 
    rm -f $(EXE) $(addprefix ${BUILD_DIR}/,$(DEPS)) $(addprefix ${BUILD_DIR}/,$(OBJECTS))

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
-include $(addprefix ${BUILD_DIR}/,$(DEPS))
endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not compiling your object files correctly. `g++` doesn't output the files to stdout, it writes them to the local directly. If you want to put the object files in a specific directory, you need to use the `-o` option:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@
                            ^^^^^^

$(BUILD_DIR):
    @mkdir -p $@
```

---

Also you're building your executable incorrectly. The dependencies are insufficient and you don't have your target listed. You'll want this:

```
$(EXE_DIR)/$(EXE) : $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR),$(OBJECTS)) | $(EXE_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(EXE_DIR):
    @mkdir -p $@
```

This will create an order-only dependency from your binary on the directory, and correctly build the binary. Note that you shouldn't have a dependency from your target on your `.d` files. That makes little sense. Instead, your rule for building the `.o`s should simply also build the `.d`s (that rule suffers the same problem currently as your `.o` rule):

```
# build the .o and the .d in one go
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : %.cpp | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ -c $< -MP -MMD -MF $(@:.o=.d)
```

---

AS AN EDITORIAL ASIDE, THERE IS THIS COMMON TENDENCY TO WRITE ALL VARIABLES IN MAKEFILES IN SHOUTY_CAPS. THIS IS PROVABLY MUCH MORE DIFFICULT TO READ THAN USING JUST USING `snake_case`. Lower case letters work just fine.

Comment: Thank you for the help and suggestions :) I've updated the makefile however I'm encountering the error main.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
In recipe for target 'bin/host/prog'.

Comment: @Mat0 Please don't edit your questions in with the answers that people give you. I've reverted your edit.

Answer (score 4):

You have two unrelated problems. The first one is that you have two conflicting `-o` options when linking.

The actual problem you ask about is something different, but still related to the `-o` option: Namely that you don't have one when attempting to create the object files.

When creating the object files, the generated object file is *not* written to standard output, therefore your redirection will not cause the `gcc` frontend program to create an object file with the name you think.

For example:

```
arm-devkit-g++ -I. -c part1.cpp > build/target/part1.o
```

The above command will create an object file named `part1.o` in the *current* directory, and write the (empty) standard output to the file `build/target/part1.o`. That will leave `build/target/part1.o` empty, which is what the linker is complaining about (that's what it means when it says the file is truncated).

The command should instead look like

```
arm-devkit-g++ -I. -c part1.cpp -o build/target/part1.o
```

Note the use of the `-o` option to name the output file.

You need to modify the makefile to not use redirection when building the object files.

---

Also, you should not list the header files when building object files, only the source file you want to build, so the command

```
arm-devkit-g++ -I. -c main.cpp part1.h part2.h > build/target/main.o
```

should really be

```
arm-devkit-g++ -I. -c main.cpp -o build/target/main.o
```